# К чему относятся .lib и .dll?

Tags: библиотеки, c++, dll

Здравствуйте. 
Файлы (для подключения функций из библиотек и пакетов. В с++) с расширениями .lib и .dll **уже заведомо не входят** в Стандартную библиотеку C++?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для начала, давайте разложим понятия по полочкам.

Формат .lib -- это принятый MSVC (возможно, и другими компиляторами) формат *статической библиотеки*, то есть, библиотеки, которая будет *вкомпилирована* компоновщиком в исполняемый модуль. У других компиляторов (в особенности -- на других системах!) может быть другой формат статических библиотек.

Формат .dll -- это принятый операционной системой Windows общесистемный формат *динамических библиотек*, то есть, библиотек, которые подключаются *во время выполнения*. Компиляторы, производящие код для Windows, обычно (но не всегда, конечно), производят динамические библиотеки в этом формате. (На других системах формат динамических библиотек, понятно, отличается.)

Рантайм-библиотека C++ -- это набор стандартных функций, которые обязаны быть доступны программе.

Статические/динамические библиотеки не оговорены в стандарте языка C++ (не путать со *стандартной* библиотекой!), его рантайм-библиотека может быть реализована как угодно на выбор авторов компилятора. Практически, однако, актуальные версии MSVC реализуют рантайм-библиотеку в обоих форматах  статической и динамической библиотеки.

В MSVC можно производить и использовать любые библиотеки, статические (.lib) и динамические (.dll). Поскольку рантайм-библиотека есть в обоих вариантах, вы можете, по своему желанию, любой из них.

Таким образом, как .dll, так и .lib может содержать как стандартную библиотеку, так и что угодно иное.

Стало яснее?

---

(Вынес из комментария, не помещается). Когда вы подключаете .h, вы *декларируете* наличие каких-то функций. Чтобы компоновщик смог найти эти функции, они должны где-то быть.

Если эти функции есть в вашем коде в другом .cpp-файле, всё уже в порядке.

Если эти функции лежат в рантайм-библиотеке, нужно подключить её как статическую или динамическую библиотеку. (Но в проекте она уже подключена, стандартный проект MSVC подключает рантайм. Или не подключает, если вы выбрали такую настройку.)

Если вы подключаете что-то ещё, тут уж вам самим придётся подключать библиотеку, в которой лежат нужные функции, иначе компоновщик не сможет их найти.

То есть: подключать нужно, просто некоторые библиотеки (например, рантайм) подключены по умолчанию.

Comment: Про статические и динамические мне ясно. Меня это всё интересует, потому что боюсь вопроса на экзамене: почему файлы .h можно подключать просто инклюдом, а другие - нет? Точнее, почему нельзя .dll and .lib сделать такими же, как .h (грубо говоря поменять расширение)? В чём отличие?

Comment: @alias: добавил в ответ.

Comment: через include можно подключать любые файлы. Даже dll. Но вот только оно скорее всего не скомпилируется. Не нужно думать, что include - это что то очень умное - это просто подстановка содержимого файла в данную строку и не более.

Comment: @KoVadim: если в header'е только шаблоны, подключать библиотеку, возможно, и не потребуется. В общем, есть много тонкостей, но топикстартеру надо для начала разобраться в основах основ.

Comment: Прочитайте мой комментарий еще раз. Под словом подключить я имел ввиду #include "file.dll" и это препроцессор пропустит. И даже, возможно, компилятор что то попытается сделать (ведь внутри файла с расширением dll может быть вовсе не dll, а обычный текстовый файл). а .h - это  не более, чем условность.

Comment: @KoVadim: я вполне понял ваш комментарий, вы уж меня за 11-летнего держите. Я имел в виду, что вы говорите о слишком уж серьёзных тонкостях, для ТС пока должно быть достаточно того, что "#include = декларация, .cpp или библиотека -- имплементация". Да, это не вся правда, знаю.

Answer (score 5):

А зачем им входить в стандарт? Это детали реализации на конкретной платформе (в данном случае - на виндовсе). Поэтому фраза "уже заведомо" как то странно звучит.

Посмотрел текущий стандарт. Там нет ни слова о dll/lib.

Comment: >Посмотрел текущий стандарт. Там нет ни слова о dll/lib.

Я бы дико удивился, если бы было сказано.

Comment: сам был бы удивлен. Но ТС так интересно написал "уже заведомо", что мне стало интересно, может я что то пропустил в этой жизни.

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понимаю, у `MSVC` *.lib - это файл архива, который в общем случае хранит набор сопоставлений "внешний символ" - ссылка на объектный (COFF или PE) файл. Этот "символ" на стадии линковки либо добавляется в исполняемый образ (в случае с COFF - из прекомпилированного объектного файла), либо - прописывается в таблице импорта (в случае с PE). Т.е. некоторый объем внешних ссылок транслируется в ваш `exe` или `dll`, через набор правил архива. Библиотеками, по большому счету - это не является, хотя и называется, как ни странно:

> The COFF archive format provides a standard mechanism for storing collections of object files. These collections **are commonly called libraries** in programming documentation.

Источник: [Microsoft Portable Executable and Common Object File Format Specification](http://kishorekumar.net/pecoff_v8.1.htm)