# Условная компиляция в статической библиотеке

Tags: c++

Можно ли реализовать условную компиляцию в статической библиотеке в зависимости от дефайнов, определенных в инклуде, без пересборки этой библиотеки?

```
-------------------------
defines.h (LIB):
#define VARIS10

-------------------------
libfile.h (LIB):
#include "defines.h"

-------------------------
libfile.cpp (LIB):
#include "libfile.h"

#ifdef VARIS10
int var = 10;
#else
int var = -10;
#endif

-------------------------
test.cpp (EXE):
#include "stdio.h"

void main()
{
extern int var;
printf( "var = %d. ", var );
}
```

Хотелось бы, чтобы при изменении дефайна в defines.h выполнялся различный участок кода в libfile без пересборки lib-а. Такое возможно? Кто не понимает, при сборке lib-а с #define VARIS10 в программе выводится "10", а без него "-10" - вне зависимости от того, с наличием или отсутствием define компилировался exe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> в зависимости от дефайнов, определенных в инклуде, **без пересборки** этой библиотеки?

Уже - нет! Препроцессор и "без пересборки" - вещи несовместимые. Препроцессор работает "над компилятором", причем именно того модуля, для которого эти зависимости требуются.
 --
Статическая библиотека работает на уровне линковщика, т.е. позднее компилятора, следовательно - учесть зависимости **уже собранных** библиотек таким образом не получится.
 --
p.s.: вот буквально [вчера объяснял](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/184144#184205), что такое статическая библиотека.

---

Чтобы не пересобирать библиотеку, Вам нужно условие `#ifdef VARIS10` вывести из препроцессора этой библиотеки, например - в функцию:

```
void Setup( bool VARIS10 ){
  if( VARIS10 ){
    var = 10
  }else{
    var = -10
  }
}
```

а в exe, допустим - оставить, если так надо:

```
extern int var;
void Setup( bool );//объявление функции стат. библиотеки
...
void main()
{
  #ifdef VARIS10
    Setup( true );
  #else
    Setup( false );
  #endif
  printf( "var = %d. ", var );
}
```

Comment: То есть того, чего бы мне хотелось, не сделать никак?

Comment: Чтобы не пересобирать библиотеку, Вам нужно условие `#ifdef VARIS10` вывести из препроцессора этой библиотеки, например - в функцию:

 void Setup( bool VARIS10 ){
   if( VARIS10 ){
     var = 10
   }else{
     var = -10
   }
 }
а в exe, допустим - оставить, если так надо:

 extern int var;
 void Setup( bool );//объявление функции стат. библиотеки
 void main()
 {
   #ifdef VARIS10
     Setup( 1 );
   #else
     Setup( 0 );
   #endif
   printf( "var = %d. ", var );
 }

Comment: Спасибо. Сделайте это ответом, я отмечу как принятый.

Comment: Отредактировал ответ.

Comment: > Препроцессор работает "над компилятором",

я бы заменил "над" на "до". А то вносит некую путаницу.

Answer (score 1):

> компиляцию
>
> без пересборки

Ни на какие мысли не наталкивает?

Comment: Ну, exe-то я перекомпилирую.

Comment: Предлагаю почитать про препроцессор.

Comment: exe не компилируется а компонуется (линкуется) а компилируются исходный и машинный коды